# Irrationality of $e^\sqrt{2}$ - reference request

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

Does anybody have a proof or know about the result by Borwein and Bailey that

> $e^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

and perhaps the motivation behind the problem and it's solution.

Comment: @DietrichBurde -  it did not pop up when I wrote the title -thanks.

Comment: For the motivation see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann–Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: In particular I was interested in the sequence [A123168](https://oeis.org/A123168)

Comment: I am going to edit my title and repost - I believe the sequence I have listed shows that $e^\sqrt{2}$ is irrational without using the Lindemann-Weirestrss Theorem

Comment: This is also shown in the duplicate without Lindemann.

Comment: Using that sequence and that specific continued fraction?

Comment: I have to look ... But if not, you could pose a new question, and you should give the reference of OEIS in the new question.

Comment: This is not a "result by Borwein and Bailey".  It follows from a result of Lindemann, which Borwein and Bailey were well aware of.

Comment: @robert israel can you elaborate?

Comment: Lindemann proved in 1882 that $e^\alpha$ is transcendental if $\alpha$ is a nonzero algebraic number.

Comment: I should have asked for an understanding of the continued fraction of $$\sqrt{2}\Bigg({e^\sqrt{2}-1 \above 1.5pt e^\sqrt{2}+1 }\Bigg)$$ and how this continued fraction proves the irrationality of $e^\sqrt{2}$